# Group specific MPI ranks to a single processing unit

Tags: binding, mapping, mpi, openmpi, pinning

I have an MPI application ( lets say `-np 6` ) in which I know ahead of time that MPI ranks `0, 2,and 3` are very light computationally compared to ranks `1, 4, and 5` and I want to conserve resource by pinning ranks `0, 2, and 3` to the same physical processing unit. Then pin ranks `1, 4, and 5` each to individual physical processing units of their own.

I know there are many flavors of MPI out there and syntax varies, however I cannot find anything out there that actually dictates the location of individual ranks, instead of just specifying a uniform 2 ppn or something to that effect. But I have to image this is possible, I am just not sure of where it falls, pinning? binding? mapping? etc.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open MPI supports what it calls rankfiles that specify the mapping of each rank to host and processing element on that host. You can see more in the [man page for `mpiexec`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.1/man1/mpiexec.1.php#sect10) (link is to documentation for v2.1 that comes with, e.g., Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but is essentially the same in newer versions too), but assuming you run everything on a single host with at least 4 CPU cores, the rankfile will look something like:

```
rank 0=hostname slot=0
rank 1=hostname slot=1
rank 2=hostname slot=0
rank 3=hostname slot=0
rank 4=hostname slot=2
rank 5=hostname slot=3
```

where `hostname` is the host name, possibly `localhost`.

Here is an example:

First, a small utility script `show_affinity` that displays the CPU affinity of the current MPI rank:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK: $(grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status)"
```

Second, a sample `rankfile`:

```
rank 0=localhost slot=0
rank 1=localhost slot=1
rank 2=localhost slot=0
rank 3=localhost slot=0
rank 4=localhost slot=2
rank 5=localhost slot=3
```

MPI launch of `show_affinity` using that rankfile:

```
$ mpiexec -H localhost -rf rankfile ./show_affinity
0: Cpus_allowed_list:   0-1
1: Cpus_allowed_list:   2-3
2: Cpus_allowed_list:   0-1
3: Cpus_allowed_list:   0-1
4: Cpus_allowed_list:   4-5
5: Cpus_allowed_list:   6-7
```

The CPU has hyperthreading enabled, so each rank gets bound to both hardware threads.